# fractional binary subtraction

Tags: math, binary, floating-point, floating-point-precision, binary-operators

I am having difficulty understanding why the following binary subtraction gives the result that it does. I keep getting a different answer. I am trying to compute 0.1-x such that x is 0.00011001100110011001100. The answer should be 0.000000000000000000000001100[1100]...(1100 keeps repeating) When i do it, I keep getting 1100 in the very beginning.

What am I not doing correctly?

Comment: What have you tried?  What exactly is your answer?  Why do you think the answer should keep repeating?

Comment: How do you know that's the answer it "should be"? That's not close to the answer I get.

Comment: Add together your 'answer should be' and your given `x`. Do you get `0.1` ? What does this say about your proposed 'answer'?

Comment: Here's another hint that your expected answer is wrong: subtracting a finite fractional value from a finite fractional value will produce a finite fractional value.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your expected answer is wrong. Here's my solution. I'll group the bits into nybbles so that it would look readable.

```
  0.1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 <- added zero to the rightmost to fill in the nybble
- 0.0001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1000 <- added zero to the rightmost to fill in the nybble
_________________________________
```

Get the 2's complement of `0.0001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1000`.

```
  1.1110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0111 (1's complement)
+ 0.0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
_________________________________
  1.1110 0110 0110 0110 0110 1000 (2's complement)
```

Add the 2's complement to `0.1`.

```
  0.1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
+ 1.1110 0110 0110 0110 0110 1000
_________________________________
 10.0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 1000
```

Since the overflow is `1`, disregard it. It just signifies that the final answer is a positive number since `0.1` is larger than `0.0001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1000`. Therefore, the final answer is `0.011001100110011001101000`.